# netifaces: Trying to get ipaddress of all Interfaces in Linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, ip-address

> Language   : Python 3.x
>
> OS         : Ubuntu 14.04

How to get all interfaces IP Address by using Python 3.X with netifaces module or by using any other module.

```
>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0', 'eth1']

>>> netifaces.interfaces()
['lo', 'eth0', 'eth1']
>>> netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')
{17: [{'broadcast': 'ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff', 'addr': '08:00:27:5b:24:09'}], 2: [{'broadcast': '10.0.2.255', 'netmask': '255.255.255.0', 'addr': '10.0.2.15'}], 10: [{'netmask': 'ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff::', 'addr': 'fe80::a00:27ff:fe5b:2409%eth0'}]}
```

I want to use

```
>>> len(netifaces.interfaces())
3
```

and want to develop some while loop which brings IPAddress for all interaces in my system. But failing at the area of substituting interface name at `netifaces.ifaddress()` function.

Please let me know if you need more information.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
list(map(lambda i:netifaces.ifaddresses(i),netifaces.interfaces()))
```

Comment: could you please explain what It will do. I am learning python.\

Comment: This is what I got , >>> map(lambda i:netifaces.ifaddresses(i),netifaces.interfaces())
<map object at 0x7f7420ccd3c8>
 and I dont know how to extract . may be googling will help me

Comment: its giving all interfaces IP address. But I have few thoughts actually. Like extracting only IPAddress of interface. I have given print i after lambda i: to get interface name as well. But I got error. and in the same way can I include a new line character

Comment: I am studying lamda maps with list now . now understood you have written a complex lamda function. can you just explain it  please . what i dont understand is how netifaces.interfaces() evaluated here and supplying argument to ifaddress().

Comment: @Raja when u use map,it takes a list and applies the given function which in our case is lambda to each of its element....

Comment: this code should be `[netifaces.ifaddresses(i) for i in netifaces.interfaces()]` - same result, pythonic, and additionally much easier to read